# SN1 Polar Protic Solvent Stabilization of Substrate

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

I know that the standard textbook answer is that a polar protic solvent is able to better stabilize/solvate carbocations through hydrogen bonding.

I understand that a solvent such as water or methanol is capable of hydrogen bonding, but what about the substrate? The substrate is a hydrocarbon; how is the substrate capable of *reciprocal* hydrogen bonding?

Is this stabilization better described as a dipole-ion interaction rather than a hydrogen bond interaction because I don't see how a hydrocarbon can form *reciprocal* hydrogen bonding interactions.

Comment: The standard explanation for the rate enhancement of SN1 in a polar protic solvent is hydrogen bonding to the leaving group, which stabilizes the building negative charge in the transition state (i.e., not the carbocation). I'm not familiar with the term reciprocal hydrogen bonding. Can you provide an example of a compound capable of this? You are right that a hydrocarbon cannot participate in hydrogen bonds.

Comment: I know water can participate in hydrogen bonding because each water molecule has a partially positive end and a partially negative end. So water molecules can hydrogen bond among themselves. But what about carbocations ... is this dipole/ion interaction a true form of hydrogen bonding?

Comment: Hydrogen bonding is a very specific type of interaction where a polarized X-H bond interacts with lone pair. The carbocation doesn't fit either component of that definition (in any traditional sense anyway).

Comment: what is **reciprocal hydrogen bonding**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I know that the standard textbook answer is that a polar protic
>   solvent is able to better stabilize/solvate carbocations through
>   hydrogen bonding.

In an $\ce{S_{N}1}$ reaction, a polar protic solvent can stabilize the leaving group through both hydrogen bonding and solvent dielectric effects.  While these same solvent dielectric effects can also stabilize the carbocation intermediate, I don't think hydrogen bonding plays a role in the stabilization of the carbocation itself.  First off, any protic molecule close enough to the carbocation to hydrogen bond would simply react with it instead of forming a hydrogen bond. Second, since the carbocation is positively charged it cannot form a hydrogen bond.  Again, solvent stabilization of the carbocation occurs through dielectric (dipolar) effects of the medium.

Comment: Can you explain the left half of this picture? http://50.57.82.128/sites/default/files/userfiles/48/uploaded_images/hbonding1.png

Comment: Not really, I see water hydrogen bonding with itself, but I don't see any dashed lines between water and the carbocation indicating any type of interaction.  So I am puzzled by their statement "H-bonds stabilize the carbocation."

Comment: Yeah I don't understand it either.

Comment: What about this can you explain this? http://o.quizlet.com/6zi2Vb-RZvTlH5S.YMksMg_m.png

Comment: In other words is the second picture describing hydrogen bonding or rather an ion dipole interaction.

Comment: ion-dipole (dipolar or dielectric) effects, not H-bonding

Comment: So why do textbooks and professors say h bonding stabilize carbocations?

Comment: Dunno, I didn't say it.  The only thing I can think of is  it can enhance the rate of carbocation formation by stabilizing the leaving group.  I just don't see how a hydrogen bond (where the H is somewhat positive) can stabilize a positive center.

Comment: But a hydrogen bond necessitates a dipole; why can't the partially negative oxygen "hydrogen bond" with the carbocation. (Scare quotes because I'm not sure if this is an actual hydrogen bond).

Comment: Here's a quote; can you explain what this means? "At the same time that the polar protic solvent is stabilizing the nucleophile, it also has the ability to stabilize any carbocations formed during the reaction. The lone pair of electrons on the solvent can donate electron density to the carbocation, making the carbocation more stable." That's not true hydrogen bonding is it? That sounds like Lewis acid/base stuff, but on the other hand, it's not permanent. I'm very confused.

Comment: That's not an H-bond.  A H-bond involves partial bonding of the hydrogen atom to something else.  What you're describing is a dipolar interaction.

Comment: "Protic solvents such as alcohols and water are even more effective solvents because anions form hydrogen bonds with the  hydrogen atom, and cations complex with the nonbonding electrons of the  oxygen atom." I agree with you ron, but this is a quote form Wade which directly states that these dipolar interactions are hydrogen bond interactions. Which makes no sense as I said in my OP and as you said in your excellent answer.

Comment: About the quote (where's it from?) - if the lone pair from the protic solvent is close enough to "stabilize", then why wouldn't it react instead?  Even if "that" (the lone pair stabilization hypothesis) happens, it is not a H-bond, it is lewis acid\base as you noted. So, 1) there is no H-bonding between the solvent and the cationic center, 2) there is dipolar stabilization of the cationic center by the solvent, 3) if the solvent is protic (like water, ethanol, acetic acid) it will react with the carbocation.

Comment: "...effective solvents because anions form hydrogen bonds with the hydrogen atom" - that's fine, that's H-bonding with the nucleophile and leaving group. "cations complex with the nonbonding electrons of the oxygen atom" well, that's OK I guess, I'd prefer to say "cations are stabilized by dipolar interaction with the nonbonding electrons on oxygen, as well as through the dielectric properties of the solvent as a whole".  Complex, stabilization - kind of similar, I guess.

Comment: The quote is from Organic Chem by Wade.

Comment: What do you mean by "dielectric properties of the solvent as a whole"?

Comment: Born equation: free energy of solvation ~ (e-1)/e times other stuff, where e is the dielectric constant of the solvent.  Therefor, the larger e, the greater the free energy of solvation of an ion in this solvent.